# Why does VMOV.F64 not allow me to load zero?

Tags: assembly, arm

The following ARM asm:

```
vmov.f64 d16, #0
```

Fails with the following error:

```
/tmp/ccZD4Iex.s:121: Error: immediate out of range -- `vmov.f64 d16,#0'
```

Compiled using arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2012.03-57) 4.6.3

How do I zero out the d16 register-double so I can use it for double precision VFP instructions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VMOV can only accept a [limited set](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHGGEEB.html) of floating-point immediates, and, surprisingly, 0 is not one of them:

> Any number that can be expressed as +/-n * 2<sup>-r</sup>, where n and r are
>   integers, 16 <= n <= 31, 0 <= r <= 7.

You can do what BitBank suggested, or use an integer move, which will also zero out the register.

```
vmov.i64 d16, #0
```

Answer (score 3):

NEON instructions don't allow you to load 64 or 128-bit immediate values into registers. The floating point value 0.0 happens to be 0x0000000000000000 also, so another way to accomplish it is with integer operations:

```
   veor.i64 d16,d16,d16
```

or you can load the value from memory (much slower)

```
 double zero[] = {0.0};

   vld1.64 d16,[zero]
```